# Implementation of Worker inside Clean Swift Architecture

Tags: swift, clean-architecture

I'm developing a new project from scratch and there are some concepts about this architecture that I would like to implement in the best way.

In many references on the Internet I can see some examples to deal with Clean Swift Architecture. In this architecture you can find that `Interactor` has a dependency of `Worker` classes

```
   protocol InteractorLogic {
     // Functions
   }

   class Interactor: InteractorLogic {
     var presenter: PresenterLogic?
     var worker: AWorker? 
   }
```

The doubt I have is about implementing this `Worker` because I saw in some examples that inside this `Worker` they put all the "use cases" related to the scene:

```
    protocol SceneWorkerLogic {

     func getPosts(success: ((Posts) -> Void), error: ((Error) -> Void)))
     func getUser(success: ((User) -> Void), error: ((Error) -> Void)))

   }

   class SceneWorker {

     func getPosts(success: ((Posts) -> Void), error: ((Error) -> Void))) {

     }

     func getUser(success: ((User) -> Void), error: ((Error) -> Void))) {

     }
   }
```

and in another examples, they divide functionality in different `Workers` like `UserWorker` and `PostWorker` where CRUD functions related with `Users` and `Posts` are implemented:

```
   protocol PostWorkerLogic {

     func getPosts(success: ((Posts) -> Void), error: ((Error) -> Void)))

   }

   class PostWorker {

     func getPosts(success: ((Posts) -> Void), error: ((Error) -> Void))) {

     }


   }
```

I consider that the second approach is better in terms of `Clean Code` but I've realized that it could be even cleaner if we use a file for a single CRUD operation like `getUser` or `getPosts`.

How can I improve this?

Comment: Having both a `success` *and* `error` completion handler isn't really good practice. I know some popular APIs (even some Apple ones, IIRC) do it, but there's a better way. First, consider what happens if you call both `success` *and* `error`? That'd be a pretty big flaw, and would blow up client code that expected mutual exclusivity. Instead, it's better to make an `enum` that stores a `Posts` object *OR* an `error` object. That way, you can never accidentally call both. It would be tedious to make one of these enums for every case like this, so you could instead make one generic one ...

Comment: But luckily for you, as of `Swift` 5, that's been introduced into the standard library, as the [`Result<T, E>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) enum. It holds either a success case (with an associated payload of type `T`), or a `failure` case (with an associated error of type `E`, where `E: Error`). Your completion handlers just need to pass a `Result<User, Error>` or `Result<Posts, Error>`.

Comment: In my code I usually create my own implementation of Result, and now we have Swift 5 version as you said. Anyway, this is not the problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: This is an example project of Clean Swift Architecture -> https://github.com/emrcftci/NSDeprem 
and this is a file template helper to create Clean Swift file effortlessly -> https://github.com/emrcftci/clean-swift-architecture-file-template

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do! The way that was showed on the clean swift book isn't my favorite...

I prefer to use workers with dependency injections to use as a facade pattern to get the data! Doing this you will have the scene worker and specific workers to do the jobs.

Example: You have a scene that present a list of movies. This list could be fetched from network or coredata so you will have a worker that receive the kind of datasource that you will use on its init method and implements a protocol with the method getMovies and this will be the scene worker! Then you will have other worker to get this from network and another one for coredata, both of them must to implement that protocol with getMovies!

I think that will be better if you get a sample app that i built from scratch using this architecture to understand it better! I really think that this way is much better than the way that he uses on his clean swift sample app (clean store).

Here is my sample app using clean swift: https://github.com/chavitos/TheMovieDB